# Kotlin null safety?

Tags: kotlin, language-design, kotlin-null-safety

Let's have a function `foo` and a class `Bar`:

```
fun foo(key: String): String? {
  // returns string or null
}

class Bar(x: String, y: String) {
  // ...
}
```

Now, let's have the code:

```
val x = foo("x")
val y = foo("y")
if (x.isNotEmpty() && y.isNotEmpty())
  return Bar(x, y)
```

The problem is that this code will not compile. Since it needs the `Bar(x!!, y!!)`.

However when I replace the function with its content, `!!` are not needed.

```
val x = foo("x")
val y = foo("y")
if ((x != null && x.length() > 0) && (y != null && y.length() > 0))
  return Bar(x, y)
```

Why it is not possible to resolve the null check from the function `.isNotEmpty()`?

Comment: Learn more about Kotlin nullable types and operators and methods for dealing with them:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498562/in-kotlin-what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-deal-with-nullable-values-referencing-o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible in theory, but it would mean that either
1. The declaration of isNotEmpty() must convey to the compiler the fact that x is guaranteed to be non-null if the result is true
2. A change to a body of any function may cause its call sites to fail to compile.

Option 2 is definitely unacceptable. Option 1 requires a rather expressive mechanism in the type system, which we decided not to add at the moment, because it is likely to complicate things for the user.

We are planning to support something like this with inline functions, but it's still under consideration.

Comment: Is there a similar feedback from dogfooding? (Since `!!` makes the code not really nice.)

Comment: @TN. It's a tradeoff: fast compiler/robust library vs more convenience. Nobody thinks it's very beautiful. If we come up with something elegant enough yet powerful, we'll definitely improve on such use cases.

Comment: I thought that inline functions are similar to macros, so it might work without extra features, or?

Comment: @TN. Conceptually, inline functions are similar to (very restricted) macros, but in fact the efficient internal representation we use implies some extra work needed to support this.

Comment: One of these options is in YouTrack as: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8889  Basically an idea to express a contract, if input values have some conditions then output will as well.   Or maybe some simple definitions based only around nullability since it is the biggest gain from something like this.